# How to solve Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

i am  upload binary file to  itunes from xcode 6.2 beta but when i am click submit to review then show "Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 SDK." please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a release version Xcode, beta version can not be used to build/upload app for app store.

Comment: @TanayBhattacharjee - Why? "Beta" is an inherited trait, compile your app with a beta compiler and your app is a beta. For production apps you use production tools and Apple enforces this.

Answer (score 0):

As @Aanabidden said, you must use a release version of Xcode to publish to the App Store. The reason is not officially stated anywhere as far as I know, but presumably the rule is in place because beta versions of Xcode can include SDK changes which might make your app not run on a release version of OS X. Since this is obviously a bad thing (customer buys an app which doesn't work and then complains to Apple) Apple simply disallows this process. If you are going to use beta versions of Xcode, you must keep the latest stable (i.e non-beta) as well if you wish to publish to the App Store.